# Hide SELECT options which has a numeric value in HTML through JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my following Select dropdown, I wanna hide the options which have only number in them (or which start with number).

As an example I wanna hide 28(2), 29(2), 35(2) and 49(2).

```
<select data-facet="field_video_tags" id="ajax-facets-selectbox-field-video-tags" name="field_video_tags" class="form-select hide processed">
   <option value="0">Select all</option>
   <option value="5">First Option (11) </option>
   <option value="38">Second Option (9) </option>
   <option value="13">Third Option (3) </option>
   <option value="28">28 (2) </option>
   <option value="29">29 (2) </option>
   <option value="35">35 (2) </option>
   <option value="49">49 (2) </option>
   <option value="8">Forth Option (2) </option>
 </select>
```

### This is what I tried:-

```
$('select#ajax-facets-selectbox-field-video-tags').filter(function() {
            return ($.isNumeric($(this).val()));
        }).addClass('hide');
```

Ofcourse, .hide is defined as {display:none} in my css.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have .hide in the class of the select option? you are hiding the entire select tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjBfl

```
$('#ajax-facets-selectbox-field-video-tags option')
  .filter(function () { return !isNaN(parseInt($(this).text())); })
  .hide();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're somehow on the right track: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/k6dLS/)

```
$('#ajax-facets-selectbox-field-video-tags option').filter(function() {
        return /^\d+/.test( $(this).text() );
}).hide();
```

Comment: You forgot the `#` in your selector.

Answer (score -1):

The behavior of applying `display: none` (which is what jQuery's `hide()` does) to `<option>`s is inconsistent between clients. So you should not rely on that and remove the elements instead.

```
$('#ajax-facets-selectbox-field-video-tags option').each(function() {
    var $option = $(this);
    if(null !== $option.text().match(/^\d/)) {
        $option.remove();
    }
})
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tSGX4/).

**Edit:** you probably *can* hide the items. But I still wouldn't recommend it. Feels like `hide()`ing a `<source>` element in an `<video>`.

Comment: Really weird. In my example they don't: http://jsfiddle.net/tSGX4/1/. Still, if they do, seems a bit "hackey" to me. `<option>`s are data sources for the `<select>` element, not visual elements.

Comment: In your example ... they are hidden for me.

Comment: Chrome 37. They don't for me. Anyway, just have a look at the edit in my post and reconsider your downvote if you agree. :) Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm ... I was using Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125 m.  That said, if you remove the `you cannot hide options` statement I'll remove my DV. Obviously you *can* hide them.

Comment: Updated my answer. Fair enough?

Comment: I agree this is a bit hacky... as an addition to hiding it, I'd go with disable, which is a valid-HTML-way of not allowing a person to select an option. Once that is done, disabled options can be set to display:none in the CSS stylesheet (instead of inline...)

Comment: I hate to turn this into a discussion, but I really feel the need to prove my point: http://i.imgur.com/2ivwdSP.png ;)